# Prevent float.Parse(string) result to epsilon number

Tags: c#, winforms, floating-point

i get the value from `textbox.Text`
i have the variable `float _value;` that store the value from textbox

```
_value = float.Parse(textBox.text);
```

when i want to show up the _value, it will be in epsilon number.
eg.

```
textbox.Text = 100000000;
```

`_value` will store with `1.0E+12`

i do want to _value store the real number 10000000.

thanks.

Comment: Really? 1.0E+12 != float.Parse("10000000")... Also it is unclear what is your question - float numbers are just numbers, how your represent them as strings is whole different story...

Comment: You might want to include what string you're providing to your textbox. "Epsilon number" is usually referred to as scientific notation.

Comment: This is not epsilon but an exponent!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value is stored in a binary floating point  format, probably IEEE754. The difference you observed is one of textual representation, when the value is converted to a string. You can control the way the values are displayed with format specifiers, to achieve your desired output,

```
float f = 1000000000000;
Console.WriteLine (string.Format("{0:.#}\n", f));
```

formats the number as "1000000000000".

More on [string.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa331875%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).